# 4 question survery - how to determine statistical significance?

Tags: statistical-significance, survey

What is the proper approach to determine the highest response rate in a multiple question survey? I did a chi square test of the most popular answer against the 2nd most popular but it feels like that's not the right approach. But I want to be able to say that for example answer b is the most popular answer at 95% significance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question boils down to the following. Consider a question that has four choices with the following results. Users ($n = 100$ users) chose

- A: 45
- B: 35
- C: 10
- D: 10

The first thing is to compare frequencies across all groups. You would do this with a $\chi^2$-test. The $\chi^2$-test tests the following hypothesis

$$
H_0: p_A = p_B = p_C = p_D \\
H_A: p_A \neq p_B \text{ or } p_A \neq p_C \text{ or } p_A \neq p_D \text{ or } ... \text{ or } p_C \neq p_D  
$$

In `R` this can be one with

```
> chisq.test(x = c(45, 35, 10, 10))

Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  c(45, 35, 10, 10)
X-squared = 38, df = 3, p-value = 2.826e-08
```

You can conclude from the test that there is some difference between all groups.

Now, what you're interested in is comparing if responses for A are greater than all other choices. You would thus need to test the following hypotheses ([comparing proportions](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/268/)):

$$
H_A: p_A > p_B \\
H_A: p_A > p_C \\
H_A: p_A > p_D \\
$$

For the first hypothesis, the null would be that $H_0: p_A = p_B = 0.5$, or that the chances of choosing A or B is 50%. You can then compare proportions. You can do this manually, or in `R` run the following:

```
> prop.test(as.table(c(45, 10)), alternative = "greater")

1-sample proportions test with continuity correction

data:  as.table(c(45, 10)), null probability 0.5
X-squared = 21.018, df = 1, p-value = 2.275e-06
alternative hypothesis: true p is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.7082738 1.0000000
sample estimates:
  p 
0.8181818
```

From this result, you can see that there is no statistical significance. However, because you'd be running multiple comparisons it is important to adjust the p-values. You can look up p-value corrections like [Bonferroni correction](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/opo.12131).

In `R` you can do this by extracting the p-value from each test, then passing it into `p.adjust` (I'm using Bonferroni corection).

```
> p = c(prop.test(as.table(c(45, 35)), alternative = "greater")$p.val,
    prop.test(as.table(c(45, 10)), alternative = "greater")$p.val,
    prop.test(as.table(c(45, 10)), alternative = "greater")$p.val)


> p.adjust(p = p, method = "bonferroni")
[1] 4.714570e-01 6.824182e-06 6.824182e-06
```

From these final results, you'd be able to state with some statistical significance if there is a difference between choices.

You may also want to summarise your results in terms of effect sizes. See: [Using Effect Size—or Why the P Value Is Not Enough](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3444174/)

Comment: This looks fishy: How do you cope with the fact that your hypotheses are all *post hoc*??  Tukey's HSD seems more promising.

Comment: @whuber that's a very good point. But isn't Tukey's HSD targeted at an ANOVA model? In this scenario, I imagine there isn't available aside from the choices A,B,C,D; Tukey's HSD would require a sums of squares <something>.